# computing the average and splitting a list on the average is not working

Tags: python

I have a list of items called cars. Each car is a tuple who's first element is a number. I am finding the average of this number amongst all cars and then attempting to split them in half on their midpoint for a divide and conquer algorithm. However, all the cars are going into the left side, and none are going into the right side.

```
    l = sum(car[1] for car in car)/2

    # all cars go in to this side 
    leftBeds = [car for car in cars if car[1] <= l]

    # no cars go into this side
    rightBeds = [car for car in cars if car[1] > l]
```

Comment: did you mean `car[1] for car in cars` or `car[1] for car in car`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to divide the sum of all cars numbers by the *number of cars* - not by 2.

```
cars = [("car 1" ,1), ("car 2",2), ("car 3",3), ("car 4",4), ("car 5",5)]

l = sum(car[1] for car in cars)/len(cars)

# all cars go in to this side 
leftBeds = [car for car in cars if car[1] <= l]

# no cars go into this side
rightBeds = [car for car in cars if car[1] > l]

print(l)
print(leftBeds,rightBeds)
```

Output:

```
3.0
[('car 1', 1), ('car 2', 2), ('car 3', 3)] [('car 4', 4), ('car 5', 5)]
```

---

If you want a midpoint, why not simply

```
lc = len(cars)
c1,c2 = cars[:lc//2], cars[lc//2:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I realized I had meant to say midpoint, not average.

Comment: @DanielPahor  the midpoint of a list is half its size - simply slice your list into two? Else: [edit] your question, provide example data and example output to clarify what you need - especially for uneven length lists.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the first line of your code:

> l = sum(car[1] for car in car)/2

It should be probably look something like:

> l = sum(car[1] for car in cars)/len(cars)

Two things: "car in cars"; and if you want the average, you should divide sum() by number of cars;

Additionally, the first element of any sequence (including tuple) has index of [0]. If you want to use the actual first element in each tuple, replace [1] with [0].